# React JS API calling done from client side or server side when code is on server.?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

Mine project architecture is as mentioned below.

End User ---> React App Server --> JAVA API server --> Database.

When I open Login page at end user by hitting (https://React App Server:port)
this is loading at end user's browser(chrome).

Now mine question is -
When end user fills User ID and Password and clicks on Login button, login API of JAVA server will go like

End User ---> React App Server --> JAVA API server --> Database.

Or

End User--> JAVA API server --> Database.

Comment: Does something happen to the login info on the react app server? Is there a reason why the login request can't just go straight to the Java API? If not, why add an extra, unnecessary step in the process? Hosting the app code and authenticating people are 2 different things, they don't need to be involved in each other's requests

Comment: Mine React App Server, JAVA API server and  Database are on intranet. End-user is only allowed to access **https://React App Server:port** , so will it work or not.?

Comment: Ok well if they CAN'T access Java API then directly then you won't even be able to go straight from end user ---> Java API. So it'll have to be end user --> React server --> Java API.

Comment: I required the same that End-User will call mine React Server and mine React Server will call JAVA server.
But it's not happening -- End user is directly trying to talk to JAVA server and hence getting TIME OUT.

Can you suggest.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After React scripts loaded to the end-user's browser, all requests are done directly to sources. React App Server as you named it is only responsible to serve all the sources and nothing more. Keep in mind it serves all the information within the React app

Long story short; **you need to put a proxy server between your React Server and the JAVA API server if you want to isolate JAVA API from the end-user**

Answer (score 0):

React app is the one which makes the api call to the server with the input data you have given in login form.
so the order is

React App <----> JAVA API server <--> Database.

Comment: Ideally this should happen like this, React App <----> JAVA API server <--> Database.

But after page rendering on client side Client is trying to talk to JAVA API Server which is not desired, I don't want expose JAVA server directly to client.

Comment: Please suggest.

Comment: what do you mean by 'do not want to expose JAVA server directly to client'. client should be the one that make api calls to server. You should make api call using axios or fetch to java rest endpoint from react app.

Comment: @Im1010 : Is there any way to make Server Side API calling.? Instead of client side.

Comment: If you don’t want to expose the api’s directly to the client then you have to use api gateway or bff layer to make the api call. But even in this case you have to call the api from client instead of server it would be of api gateway or bff layer